# Using codeigniter to update multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to update multiple rows at a time in codeigniter.  I have the following a an example of the fields I need to update for each user

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="id[46][firstname]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="id[46][lastname]" value="">
</div>

<div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="id[48][firstname]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="id[48][lastname]" value="">
</div>
```

I am struggling to grab the values for update.  The actual update statement shouldn't be a problem, I'm just concerned with retrieving the correct form values per user.

```
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $keyparts = explode('_', $key);
        if(count($keyparts) == 2){
            switch ($keyparts[0]) {
                case 'firstname':
                    $records[$keyparts[1]]->firstname = $value;
                    break;
                case 'lastname':
                    $records[$keyparts[1]]->lastname = $value;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        // update statement to go here
    }
```

Comment: You should avoid using $_POST when using Codeigniter as they have a better function for this `$this->input->post('field_name')'.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code

```
<div class="row">
<input type="text" name="46[firstname]" value="">
<input type="text" name="46[lastname]"  value="">
</div>

<div class="row">
<input type="text" name="48[firstname]" value="">
<input type="text" name="48[lastname]" value="">
</div>
```

PHP Code

```
$records = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

    if(is_array($value))
    {
        foreach($value as $new_key=>$new_val)
        {
            $records[$key][$new_key] = $new_val;
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not understanding how your POST is building the array. From you HTML above, the form will build the following POST array:

```
array =>
    [id] =>
        [46] =>
            [firstname] => "john"
            [lastname] => "doe"

        [48] =>
            [firstname] => "jane"
            [lastname] => "doet"
```

with the array being visually laid out like that, you can now iterate, to obtain your values. However, one thing I do not understand in your code, is why you are using `explode()`, what are you trying to turn into an array? You can easily iterate and update this information in your database like so:

```
$this->load->model("my_model");
$postdata = $this->input->post();
foreach($postdata['id'] as $id => $user_info){
     $this->my_model->update_user($id, $user_info); // your model method should handle the update information by ID.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do `echo "<pre>" .print_r($_POST, true)."</pre>";` on the form processing page,  the result should look linke this

```
    Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [46] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => firstNameValue1
                    [lastname] => lastNameValue1
                )

            [48] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => firstNameValue2
                    [lastname] => lastNameValue2
                )

        )

)
```

So, this should help you catch the values:

```
foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $value){
  $records[$key] = (object)array();
  $records[$key]->firstname = $value['firstname'];
  $records[$key]->lastname = $value['lastname'];

    // update statement to go here
}
```

Results this structure:

```
Array
(
    [46] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstname] => firstNameValue1
            [lastname] => lastNameValue1
        )

    [48] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstname] => firstNameValue2
            [lastname] => lastNameValue2
        )

)
```